# Drag formula to the last row (take first cell as A6)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to fill the formula till the last used row. I have data from A6:A28, however while using below code its dragging the formula till row 628. Issue is with 4th line of the code. Please help me correct.

```
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("H6:M6").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H6:M6" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: Please post the actual code you're using.  `Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` is not a valid line of code unless you've defined `Rows` as some variable.  It will throw a 424 Object required error in its current form.

Comment: @TehDrunkSailor: `Rows.Count` is a thing: it is actually short for `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` (e.g. `1048576` or `65536` for older versions). Remember the [Range.Rows property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.rows).

Comment: @VBasic2008 Whoops!  I completely missed that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Down Formulas

**A Quick Fix**

- Just remove the `6` after the `M`.

```vb
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H6:M" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

**An Improvement**

- No `Select`
- No variable
- No `AutoFill`

```vb
With ActiveSheet ' improve!
    With .Range("H6:M" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = .Rows(1).Formula
    End With
End With
```